# svg drawn to canvas positioned and scaled wrong

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, firefox, canvas

I am drawing a simple svg onto a canvas.  On Firefox the x position and width of the svg are not correct - pushed too far to the right and not wide enough.

Here is the svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300">
<rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="300" fill="#f00"/>
</svg>
```

and here is the simple javascript:

```
var i = new Image();
i.addEventListener("load", () => {
  var c = document.getElementById("c");
  c.style.border = "1px blue solid";
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(i, 20, 20, 460, 260);
});
i.src = "test.svg";
```

Here is how chrome renders the svg on the canvas - note the indentation of 20px looks correct.

[image: chrome canvas]

But contrast that with how it renders on firefox.  Note its left indentation is greater than 20px and the width is scaled too small.

[image: firefox canvas]

You can demo the issue here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/scaled-svg-in-canvas-5fv11

Is there a workaround to this issue?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems like Chrome isn't preserving the aspect ratio of your SVG correctly. I.e. 5:3

Comment: @RobertLongson thx!  That solves it.

Comment: @RobertLongson according to Chrome's team their behavior is the correct one. See https://crbug.com/1018487#c10 Something in my gut says this is not expected behavior but their reading of the specs sounds legit. WDYT? Should an issue be opened on FF or even on the specs? That's anyway an interop issue.

Comment: And according to Firefox, ours is. So you'd need to get this addressed by w3c. It may be that the w3c canvas specification and the w3c SVG specification are inconsistent with each other. Firefox is following the SVG specification more closely and Chrome the canvas specification more closely.

Comment: @RobertLongson W3C doesn't do canvas anymore, but I'm willing to open an issue on WHATWG, with which I'm more familiar and gather thoughts there. However I would have enjoyed having more arguments to start this discussion than my poor gut feelings. Could you link to which part of the SVG specs would apply here?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute

Comment: @RobertLongson if you want to participate, I opened https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6546